# How to call a function before a functional component render in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I have a `<Loading />` component that wraps all routes in my app.
The `<Loading />` component has a property `isLoading` that receives a Redux state variable, that tells if the `Loading` component will be visible or not.

```
function App() {
    const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.loading.value)
    
    return (
        <Loading isLoading={isLoading}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Hypertube />} />
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Loading>
    );
}
```

When the user opens a page, I need to change the Redux state to true, so the `<Loading />` component will be visible (and then hide it when the page gets rendered).
So what I need, is to change the state before the functional component gets rendered (or while the component is rendering).

I wanted to use `componentWillMount()`, but it's deprecated now.

A solution to this (that I don't like) is to do this 2 changes:

1. Set the default redux state value to true, so we can see the loading whenever the page get opened for the first time.
2. Change the state value to `true` whenever the user get redirected to another page.

Comment: Why isn't the default value `true`?

Answer (score 2):

> How to call a function before a functional component render in ReactJS

Theoretically you could dispatch an action on component's mount (in `useEffect` hook) to set the loading state to `true`, but a single flick *may be* visible (because the component will have to *re-render*).

A standard solution for it is to set the default value of `state.loading.value` to `true` in the redux store.

If you want to set the loading value to `true` with every route change, you could e.g. listen to the `location` change:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(setLoadingToTrueAction());
}, [location]);
```

Or you could just dispatch this action in every component within `useEffect` where you want the loader to appear.

Comment: @arrmani88 You want to show the loader with every route change, right?

Comment: should I add this only in `App()` function ?

Comment: @arrmani88 Check firstly if it works for you well :)

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, thank you so much your solution is working, I also will let you know if I find a way how to call a function before a functional component render